# Place an element after an HTML select and fade out

Tags: jquery, html, select, image

How can I place an `img` element right after a `select` and have it fade out ?

What I've tried so far:

- `appendTo` is not suitable as it places elements inside the `select` element.
- `after` needs to be called from the `select` element so chaining a `fade` will act on the `select` and not the `img`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

Using this the chaining effect will be attached to the image element.

```
$(function() {
    $('<img class="pub-cover" src="http://i.imgur.com/vER9H.png" />')                  
        .insertAfter('select').fadeOut('slow')
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RmRTp/)

Comment: You forgot to change the info link title in the answer.